# Can a polytheistic culture survive even if surrounded by monotheistic centralized aggressive warlike cultures like Christianity and Islam?

Tags: warfare, culture, civilization, religion

Let's say a pagan polytheistic culture survives in the Middle East, with some fertile land and a couple hills to be able to defend itself, while still being a hub for trade. Would it be able to evolve and reach a high civilization level even if it got encroached by hostile and aggressive warlike centralized monotheistic cultures like Christianity and Islam?

Comment: Does Hinduism not fit the bill for some reason?

Comment: This is a history question, not a worldbuilding question. Do take a look at our [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how this forum works.  We're here to help you devise your own fictional world, not satisfy idle curiosity about real world events or enter basic search criteria into the Googlematic for you.

Comment: India seems to be doing just fine.  So's Japan, though I don't know if that meets your criteria for "surrounded".  Also note that Roman & other pre-Christian European cultures weren't usually subjugated to Christianity by force, but by subversion from within.

Comment: @elemtilas Umm, whut?  Granted the fictional posit is vague and unspecific, but he's positing something that doesn't/didn't exist in the real world, and if it did - got eaten by Christian / Islamic cultures.

Comment: Manichaeism and Zoroastrianism were/are able to survive in the Middle East for quite some time. They aren't quite as polytheistic as Greco-Roman paganism or Hinduism (whether Manichaeism or Zoroastrianism are monotheistic or polytheistic is a complex question), but they aren't Christian or Muslim sects.

Comment: @user3082 - Basic real world history question. Positing "Middle East" in stead of "South Asia" doesn't exactly make a question about worldbuilding and wouldn't substantially alter the answer from "are you aware of the existence of India?".

Comment: @elemtilas Because Islam and Christianity threatened India?  o_O  And, TIL India was a small nation, with a couple hills; instead of a subcontinent bounded by mountains and oceans.

Comment: @user3082 -- Ah, good. So you have heard of India! Now you know why the query was closed.

Comment: @elemtilas *WHOOOSH*

Answer (score 1):

Not without expanding.  Small fish get eaten by larger and aggressive states, unless they have significant advantages (Switzerland, Lesotho).  Monotheism is a disadvantage to large states/empires, but not enough of a disadvantage to prevent them from existing.  Polytheism is an advantage, except when you need to mobilize your population for existential crises (and can jury-rig up a religious 'reason' for conquering... say the 'Holy Land').

Comment: How is Monotheism a disadvantage to empires whereas polytheism is an advantage? Most of the largest empires in history were controlled by monotheistic societies (The Ottoman empire, the Spanish Empire, the British Empire, the United States' empire..etc), even Rome existed as a Monotheistic empire much longer than it existed as a polytheistic one.

Comment: @user110866 I am not sure if he meant that, but synchretism allow you to integrate heterogenous population into your empire, by mixing both religions. This is not possible with a dogmatic monotheism.Rome make expand the most during it's republic phase, in a pagan europe, not during the empire. And sure, the eastern roman empire survives long enough, but the population was already  quite integrated into the empire. British and Spanish empires were colonial empire, with a big asymmetry, both during the conquest, war, but even after, when the mainland and the colony didn't have the same status.

Comment: @user110866 See: Arnaldo Momigliano, "The Disadvantages of Monotheism for a Universal State", Classical Philology 81.4 (1986) 285297 - jstor is offering 100 free articles a month for a minute.

Comment: @user3082 thanks for the pointing me to the article, fortunately I already have access to JSTOR and will be sure to read it.

Comment: @Kepotx those are very good points...

Comment: @user110866 Also (not found a good reference), but Soviet Russia was able to take many cultures, and get a (mostly) working military machine out it.  I'd like to read more about that.  US, obviously, has as well.

Comment: @user3082 but Soviet Russia was, while officially atheistic was far from, the Russian orthodox church did and still does have much power and there are many political, scientific and military figures who still are fairly devote members. In fact the Russian orthodox church currently has more members than the entire population of Russia